# How would $F(x)$ look given this graph of $F'(x)$?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

[image]

*We know $F(0) = 0$*

Okay, I just need some intuition on how to do this. So far, all I know is that the slope of $F(x)$ is always positive, therefore I should not have a negative slope anywhere on my graph. Other than that, I have no idea what I can do to graph $F(x)$ given $F'(x)$.

Comment: You also know that at $x \approx 2.2$, $f'(x)=0$ so the slope of $f$ is 0 at that point, but as you mentionned $f$ is increasing before and after this value. Can you begin to draw the graph of $f$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following figure the red line represents $f$. $f$ is non-decreasing since the derivative is non-negative. $f$ has $0$ slope and slope $2$ as show (red numbers). $f$ has inflection points where ever $f'$ has local minima.

[image]

Comment: I see where I got confused. I had thought that the graph of f(x) must be positive throughout as well, which is why I didn't quite understand how I can get an increasing graph to hit 0 if it is always positive, but I had a similar shape in mind. Thanks, this clears it up and so do the other answers.

Comment: Shouldn't F(x) be positive for x < 0 as well?  F'(x) >= 0 for all x.  I think you need to reflect the left half of your graph over the x-axis.

Comment: @Gaussian0617: No: (1) the derivative does not say anything about the sign of the function. (2) The derivative is non-negative every where, as a result the function is increasing, so it cannot be reflected over the $y$ axis.

Comment: @zoli, of course you're right; I don't know what I was thinking.  Editing my answer to reflect your correction.

Answer (score 1):

Some intuition about the shape:

Starting from $x = 0$ and going to the right of the $y$-axis, you begin with your maximum slope which begins to decrease immediately; so $F(x)$ is increasing and concave until the slope flattens at $F'(x) = 0$ at around $x = 2.2$.  At this point, the $F'(x)$ begins to increase so $F(x)$ enters a region where it is convex with an increasingly steep slope until about $x = 4$, at which point $F(x)$ enters a region where its slope is decreasing making it concave again until just after $x = 5$, etc.

This cycle between concave and convex repeats itself so that $F(x)$ should be a monotonically increasing function whose slope behavior causes it to repeat an S shape as the function increases.  This behavior is reflected about the origin.